# Autolayout - Define which constraint should change adjust it's size first

Tags: constraints, autolayout

I have defined multiple constraints with Greater Than or Equal and Less Than or Equal. How does iOS decide which view will change its size when the superview changed its size?

Let's assume I have one view with constraints Greater Than 10 and Less Than 20.
And I got a second view with the constraints Greater Than 40 and Less Than 60.

Now the superview changes its size and the available space will increase by 10 pixel. I need a way to define which constraint is allowed to resize first (and take the 10pixel).

Answer (score 1):

NSLayoutConstraint's priorities tell iOS & OS X which constraints to satisfy first.

If you have a view `viewOne` that you'd like to expand first, apply a constraint with visual format `@"H:[viewOne(==9999@499)]"`. That will tell iOS that, after the required constraints  `10≤viewOne≤20` & `40≤viewTwo≤60` are met, it should attempt to make `viewOne` 9,999 pixels wide, causing it to expand before `viewTwo`.

If you don't want to store the magic number 9999,

```
NSNumber* maxWidthForViewOne = @(20) ;
NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[viewOne(==asBigAsPossible@499)]"  options:0  metrics:@{@"asBigAsPossible":maxWidthForViewOne}  views:views] [0] ;
```

I tested these in OS X, and I found that 499 (NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut - 1) was the highest priority that allowed me to shrink `viewOne` by resizing the window. Since you're using iOS, you'll want to test what priority behaves as you like.